# socket.error: [Errno 10060]: Unable send an email from outlook using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, outlook, ms-office

I've below code which was working fine for months. Now, it is giving me the error below,

> socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

```
        sender = 'myemail@email.com'
        receiver = ['myemail@email.com',]
        msg = MIMEMultipart()

        print("Sending an email to {} ...".format(receiver))

        msg['From'] = sender
        msg['To'] = ", ".join(receiver)
        msg['Subject'] = 'Automation Testing'

        body = 'Hello,' 
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
        # filename = 'Fidelity-Success' + timestamp + '.png'
        attachment = open('C:\\mydrive\\{}'.format(filename), 'rb')

        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload((attachment).read())
        # part.set_payload((attachment).read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= " + filename)

        msg.attach(part)

        server = smtplib.SMTP('mail.email.com', 587, timeout=120)
        #server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('mail.email.com', 93, timeout=120)

        server.starttls()
        server.login(sender, "password")
        text = msg.as_string()
        server.sendmail(sender, receiver, text)
        # server.quit()
        time.sleep(4)
        print("Email sent.")
```

I tried various ports and timeout but no luck. I am not sure why it stopped working all of a sudden.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory. You had a connection issue.

Comment: @Joel Yes, but I am not able to figure out what went wrong

Comment: A connection issue is outside the scope of your program. Maybe there's a problem with your Wifi, or perhaps your mail server had an issue on their end.

Comment: @Joel Is there any way to find root cause? I am really stuck here, not sure how to troubleshoot.

Comment: I don't know whether I was able to ping the mail and smtp server but, now when I ping mail.xxx.com and smtp.xxx.com, I get timed out. Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a network issue. I just had to add IPs of mail and smtp server.

Temporary fix: Run following commands in command prompt in admin mode:

```
route add 'IP of mail server' mask 255.255.255.255 'default gateway of your machine'
route add 'IP of smtp server' mask 255.255.255.255 'default gateway of your machine'
```

Permanant fix: Ask network team to add mail server's IP to split tunnel.